# Should the seed be set in forecasting returns in a MCMC

Tags: markov-chain, forecasting

Suppose we are estimating a linear model utilizing a Markov Chain Monte Carlo technique such as a Gibbs sampler, drawing from the posteriors in a Bayes framework.  Suppose the full sample of data we have is from time $t = 1, \dots,\tau\dots, T$, and we want to forecast returns one period ahead using a recursive window starting at time $t = \tau$ until time $t = T$. We have trained the model from time $t=1$ to time $t=\tau$, then we want to forecast returns out of sample at time $t=\tau+1$:

\begin{equation} y_{\tau +1} = \beta' \mathbf{x}_\tau + \sigma \varepsilon_{\tau + 1}, \; \; \varepsilon_{\tau + 1} \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1) \end{equation}

When I tried this without setting the seed at each period the error term $\varepsilon_{\tau+1}$ was so stochastic across the $I$ iterations of the MCMC algorithm that $y_{\tau+1}$ was essentially a random walk.  When I set the seed at each period such that the $I$ iterations in the Gibbs sampler used the same $\varepsilon_{\tau+1}$ I found much better results in terms of RMSFE.

Should we set the seed in the random number generator in each period $\tau$, such that all $I$ iterations of evaluating $y_{\tau+1}$ use the same error term $\varepsilon_{\tau+1}$ when computing this forecast?

Comment: By seed, do you mean $X_0$? Do you mean seeding the random number generator? If not, can you please update your question to be more precise about what you mean? Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out, I mean the random number generator.   But I think I have realized the answer to this is to not include the random term in the forecast equation at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My understanding is that the standard advice is to randomly select a seed value, and then keep that seed for your entire analysis. This allows the same computer code to give identical results each time.

See, for example, the [Stata manual](https://www.stata.com/manuals13/rsetseed.pdf):

> Stata’s random-number generation functions, such as runiform() and
>   rnormal(), do not really produce  random  numbers.  These  functions 
>   are  deterministic  algorithms  that  produce  numbers  that can  pass
>   for  random. runiform() produces  numbers  that  can  pass  for 
>   independent  draws  from  a rectangular distribution over[0,1);
>   rnormal()produces numbers that can pass for independent draws from
>   N(0,1).  Stata’s random-number functions are formally called
>   pseudorandom-number functions.The  sequences  these  functions 
>   produce  are  determined  by  the  seed,  which  is  just  a  number 
>   andwhich  is  set  to  123456789  every  time  Stata  is  launched.
>   ... If you record the seed you set, pseudorandom results such as
>   results from a simulation or imputed values  from mi impute can  be 
>   reproduced  later.  **Whatever  you  do  after  setting  the  seed, 
>   if  you  set the seed to the same value and repeat what you did, you
>   will obtain the same results** ... It does not really matter how you
>   set the seed, as long as there is no obvious pattern in the seeds that
>   you set and as long as you do not set the seed too often during a
>   session

However, if you are using parallelization to do many separate simulations then you need to make sure that you do not use the same seed, or a time based seed, on every node:

> Properly seed your generator. Even the state-of-the-art Mersenne
>   Twister ran into problems early on because the authors had neglected
>   the issue of proper seeding....This rule is VITAL if you are going to
>   run parallel simulations on a Beowulf cluster for example.The simplest
>   way to seed a RNG is to take something like the current time e.g.
>   using the time() function found in Unix and most C libraries, which
>   returns a 32-bit integer giving the number of seconds since 1st Jan
>   1970. ...Hundreds of jobs on different nodes will be starting at almost exactly the same time –therefore many of your jobs will be
>   starting with exactly the same seed and therefore those that have the
>   same seed will generate exactly the same results(assuming your code
>   has no bugs in it).

[Good Practice in (Pseudo) Random Number Generation for Bioinformatics Applications](http://www0.cs.ucl.ac.uk/staff/D.Jones/GoodPracticeRNG.pdf)

Comment: Yup, plus: always run your analysis against different seeds as a robustness check. Present your results for the one seed, but if they’re highly sensitive to the seed value, you have a problem.